# Как добиться такой адаптивности блока?

Tags: css

Делаю автоподстройку постеров на своём проекте, но не получается сделать так, чтобы изображение подстраивались как нужно.

Имеется постер размером width 254px а height 360px
стало быть, если мы изменим ширину скажем так: width 280px то высота постера должна быть: height 397px. Что тут можно придуамать? Хотелось бы сделать какую то формулу расчёта высоты от ширины, но я не пойму, как расчитать сколько нужно добавить к высоте, когда меняется ширина... Нужно чтобы при любой ширине увеличивалась и высота так, как я описал выше. Также, прошк учесть, что используется display grid - может при помощи него можно сделать. Я знаю о @media но так выходит, что нужно учесть кучу разрешений и нужно описать кучу вариантов изменений, чтобы добится нормальной подстройки.

Пример чего хочу добиться:
[image: пример]

Comment: С помощью css в голову aspect-ratio приходит: `aspect-ratio: calc(attr(width) / attr(height))`, как то так. Но я не уверен, что это хорошая идея. Лучше бы с помощью js реализовать

Comment: это у Вас для печати или для скачивания размеры?

Comment: @DaniilLoban в смысле? это постеры на сайте. я просто показал пример, где наглядно видно как изменяется высота, если задать ширину

Comment: понял, я думал либо для скачивания либо для печати на принтере

Comment: @Арман да не, норм. хоть и свойство не шибко поддерживается браузерами. в частности последними версиями

Answer (score 1):

Старый способ - `padding`, новый `aspect-ratio`.

```css
div {
  margin: 2.5%;
  width: 40%;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}

div:first-child::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 50%;
}

div:last-child {
  aspect-ratio: 2;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Это также решает мою проблему, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Основная фишка использование `aspect-ratio` в качестве задания размера, но при этом обязательно одна из сторон должна быть строго забита, если установлены 2 стороны `aspect-ratio` не работает, однако в программе я это решаю в `updateSize`. Можно использовать фиксированную высоту или ширину, тоже очень удобно если масштаб не нужен.

```js
/*
Имеется постер размером width 254px а height 360px стало быть, если мы изменим ширину скажем так: width 280px то высота постера должна быть: height 397px. Что тут можно 
*/

const w = document.getElementById('width');
const h = document.getElementById('height');
const z = document.getElementById('zoom');
const p = document.getElementById('page');

let oldW = 254
let oldH = 360
let oldZ = 0.5
let aspect = oldW / oldH

function updateSize(){
  p.style.height = `${oldH * oldZ}px`
  p.style.width = `${oldW * oldZ}px`
  p.style.aspectRatio = `${oldW} / ${oldH}`
}
updateSize()

function updateHeight(target){
  if (oldW && oldH){
    oldH = target.value
    w.value = Math.round(oldH * aspect)
    oldW = w.value
    p.style.height = `${oldH * oldZ}px`
    updateSize()
  } else {
    oldH = event.target.value
  }
}
function updateWidth(target){
  if (oldW && oldH){
    oldW = target.value
    h.value = Math.ceil(oldW / aspect)
    oldH = h.value
    p.style.width = `${oldW * oldZ}px`
    updateSize()
  } else {
    oldW = event.target.value
  }
}

w.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  updateWidth(event.target)
}, false)

h.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  updateHeight(event.target)
}, false)

z.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  oldZ = event.target.value
  if (oldW && oldH){
    updateSize()
  } 
}, false)
```

```css
body {
 background: gray;
}

div {
  /* height:100px; фиксированная высота */
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  aspect-ratio: 254 / 360;
}
```

```html
<label>
ширина:
<input id="width" type="number" value="254" >
</label>
<label>
высота:
<input id="height" type="number" value="360">
</label>
<label>
масштаб:
<input id="zoom" type="range" min="0.1" value=".5" step="0.01" max="1">
</label>
<div id="page"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, хороший пример, который решает задачу

Comment: Рад, что удалось помочь.

Comment: может знаете, как можно решить проблему с этим https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1455501/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%85%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5

Comment: а какой телефон `android`, `iphone` ?

Comment: android браузер google. да и у яндекса вообще беда, их панель ещё хуже и она внизу...

Comment: a https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/ как отобразится?

Comment: не понимаю что за ```mdn``` ? ааа.. понял сейчас гляну

Comment: у mdn другая вёрстка... он норм, но там иначе всё

Comment: просто я `mdn` доверяю, сделайте вопрос отдельный и скиньте верстку я попробую решить, желательно минимальную верстку без деталей