# Как можно побороть верхнею панель у мобильных браузеров в этом примере?

Tags: css

Столкнулся с проблемой в мобильных браузерах.

Проблема: на смартфоне в браузере Google Chrome - есть верхняя панель, а в Я.Браузер - есть нижняя панель. Эта панель занимает определённое пространство и в следствии чего, моя нижняя панель (помечена красной стрелкой на рисунке ниже) пропадает. Если листать содержимое сайта, то панелька браузера пропадает и тогда мою панельку становится видно... Как такое можно поправить?

**Пример кода сайта:**

```
body { 
    width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.class {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.content {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.panel_down {
    height: 60px;
}

<body>
<div class="class">
    <div class="content">тут контент</div>
    <div class="panel_down">это панель</div>
</div>
</body>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблему не обнаружить, если использовать devtools десктопного браузера. её хорошо видно на браузере смартфона.

Вариант использовать height: calc(100vh - 60px); знаю, но это решение не очень хорошее. Мне кажется, что поведение будет проблемным.

Answer (score 1):

Решением этой проблемы будут новые единицы измерения lvh, lvw, svh, svw, dvh, dvw. Но пока что у них почти никакая поддержка, особенно на мобильных.
https://caniuse.com/viewport-unit-variants

На мой взгляд вариант описанный на css-tricks не идеальный, но лучший из имеющихся на данный момент. Сразу стоит отметить, что данный способ не стоит использовать как есть, нужно как минимум добавить debounce к resize
https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/

```js
function setModuleHeight() {
  // First we get the viewport height and we multiple it by 1% to get a value for a vh unit
  const vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
  // Then we set the value in the --vh custom property to the root of the document
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
}

// We listen to the resize event
window.addEventListener('resize', setModuleHeight);
setModuleHeight();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #333;
}

.module {
  height: 100vh;
  height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 30%;
}

.module__item {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 20%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.module__item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #F73859;
}

.module__item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #F73859;
  color: #F1D08A;
}
```

```html
<div class="module">
  <div class="module__item">20%</div>
  <div class="module__item">40%</div>
  <div class="module__item">60%</div>
  <div class="module__item">80%</div>
  <div class="module__item">100%</div>
</div>
```

Более подробно можно прочесть на англоязычном SO

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser

Comment: Вообще беда, опять ждать пока нативную поддержку завезут. Особенно да, на мобильных браузерах в 150+ версии